# Eliminate unnecessary Piecewise terms from Sympy expressions

Tags: sympy

Sympy often produces expressions like

```
Sum(Piecewise((2**(-N)*exp(-_k*beta)*binomial(N, _k), _k <= N), (0, True)), (_k, 0, N))
```

where the first condition of the `Piecewise` is always satisfied, since it is ensured by the summation range.

In this example I can eliminate the Piecewise using

```
X.refine(Q.le(X.bound_symbols[0], N))
```

which works because I know the form of the expression.

I would like to find a general solution that can eliminate redundant `Piecewise` case anywhere in an expression in most reasonable cases without knowing the structure of the expression in advance, since it needs to be applied to results of other simplifications. Something like "refine by implicit constraints on bound variables". None of the simplification functions seem able to do this.
Note that the summation variable is introduced by Sympy so I do not have control over its creation.

Comment: The task as posed is too broad: "a general solution that can eliminate redundant Piecewise case anywhere in an expression and does not require knowing the structure of the expression". That's mathematically impossible per Richardson's theorem. If you limit the scope then there are cases for which this is solvable.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin You are correct. I meant some kind of heuristics solution like the simplification functions themselves are. I have updated the question to better indicate scope of what am after.

Comment: So you want to eliminate redundant Piecewise where the conditions are based on some bound symbol such that the bounds of the symbol can resolve the conditions in the Piecewise?

Comment: What is the sympy result that leads to the Piecewise in the Sum here? Presumably the Piecewise just shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin that is what I want. It usually comes out the sympy.stats.E call on a rather complex distribution. Not sure why it gets there in the first place. I would prefer to avoid getting it in the first place, but not really sure how. Failing that I would like a systematic way of getting rid of them when they do

Comment: You can use this `e.replace(lambda x: x.is_Piecewise, lambda x: x.args[0][0])` if the first part of the Piecewise is always the bit you want. Generally I think it's a bug though so can you open an issue? https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues